# Continue selenium script after error "Failed to decode response from marionette"

Tags: python, selenium

I have a python script that lists the title of a long list of websites. It takes a long time, so the script has to run for hours. However, sporadically, I'll get the error "Failed to decode response from marionette."

Given what I've read, it doesn't seem like the reason behind the error is fully well known. It is not a priority for me to get rid of it, but rather not to stop the script altogether when it occurs, which is what currently happens when the error is given.

How would I do that?

This is the code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from time import sleep
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
display = Display(visible=0, size(800,600))
display.start()
urlsFile = open ("urls.txt", "r")
urls = urlsFile.readLines()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/geckodriver/geckodriver')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
for url in urls:
        try:
           driver.get(url)
           sleep(0.8)
           print(driver.title)
        except TimeoutException as e:
           print("Timeout")
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `driver.get(url)` line is the one that throws the exception?

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is my first attempt at writing Python

---

You just need to build in a way to retry the GET operation if it fails. You will still want to give up on a certain number of retries, but at least this should catch the one-off failures per URL.

```py
def retryable_get(self, url, max_tries = 5)
  attempts = 0
  while attempts < max_tries
    try:
      self.get(url)
    except Exception:
      puts 'An error occured performing a GET to ' + url
    finally:
      attempts += 1
  raise TimeoutException(f'Failed to GET {url} after {max_tries} attempts')
```

You can call it using:

```py
retryable_get(driver, url)
```

Or duck-type the Firefox class if you want a more object oriented-like approach:

```py
webdriver.Firefox.retryable_get = retryable_get

for url in urls:
  try:
    driver.retryable_get(url)
    sleep(0.8)
    print(driver.title)
  except TimeoutException as e:
    print("Timeout")
```